# Getting error 23 in Hikvision camera integration

Tags: hikvision

Using Hikvision sdk some command of API(NET_DVR_GetDVRConfig) is working but some command are showing error 23(server does not support).I used this command(NET_DVR_GET_IPPARACFG_V40)
 but I am getting error 23. I want to know what this message mean either my camera does not support or I am doing something wrong?.

Answer (score 0):

This PDF might come in useful for someone. Check page 136

http://ftp.hikvision.ru/09.%20%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B/9.%20SDK/Device%20Network%20SDK%20Programming%20Manual%28IPC%29.pdf

Error 23 is:

```
NET_DVR_NOSUPPORT - Device does not support this function
```